# How to override abstract class constructor in sub class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, abstract

Ive just moved from java to c++ and I'm really struggling with what were once basic concepts. All I want to do is create an abstract class called 'Spaceship', give it a constructor that takes 4 arguments, and then in a sub class called 'Alienspaceship', I want to make a constructor that takes 5 arguments but inherits the 'spaceship' constructors first 4 arguments. Ive been looking all over the place and can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. Below is my code. Please and thank you to anyone who can help me!

header

```
#ifndef SPACESHIP
#define SPACESHIP

#include "Enum.h"

class Spaceship{
    public:
    float health;
    float food;
    float cash;
    float misc;

public:
    Spaceship(float, float, float, float);

};

class AlienSpaceship: public Spaceship{
    OrganismType race;

    public:
        AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType):Spaceship(float, float, float, float){}
};

#endif
```

cpp

```
#include "Spaceship.h"

Spaceship::Spaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc){
    this->health = health;
    this->food = food;
    this->cash = cash;
    this->misc = misc;
}

AlienSpaceship::AlienSpaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc, OrganismType race):Spaceship(health, food, cash, misc){
    this->race = race;
}
```

Comment: `AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType):Spaceship(float, float, float, float){}` is a definition! It's conflicting with the out-of-class definition in your cpp file. I suspect you made a typographical error while refactoring. Forgot to update something you moved, as it were.

Comment: Offtopic: note that data members can (should?) be initialized before the body of the constructor and you don't need this->. Thus: Spaceship::Spaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc): health(health), flood(flood), cash(cash), misc(misc) {}

Comment: Your `Spaceship` class isn't abstract, by the way. It's a concrete class. At least with the code you show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is that because it doesn't contain virtual functions?

Comment: An abstract class have virtual functions that are "initialized" to zero (like e.g. `virtual void abstract_function() = 0;`). A pure abstract class have *only* abstract functions (so no constructors or destructors even).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how the constructor initializer list works.

It's used in the *definition* (i.e. implementation) of the constructor, it's not needed for the declaration of your constructor.

In fact, your current declaration in the `AlienSpaceship` class actually *defines* (implements) the constructor, because of the ending `{}`.

So for the class, all you need to do is

```
class AlienSpaceship: public Spaceship{
    ...
    public:
        AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType);
};
```

---

On a related note, I suggest you use initializer lists to initialize member variables as well, then your constructors could be just

```
Spaceship::Spaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc)
    : health(health), food(food), cash(cash), misc(misc)
{ /* Empty */ }

AlienSpaceship::AlienSpaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc, OrganismType race)
    : Spaceship(health, food, cash, misc), race(race)
{ /* Empty */ }
```

And of course this could be done inline in the class definition itself:

```
class AlienSpaceship: public Spaceship{
    ...
    public:
        AlienSpaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc, OrganismType race)
            : Spaceship(health, food, cash, misc), race(race)
        { /* Empty */ }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType):Spaceship(float, float, float, float){}`

should just be:

`AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType);`

in your header. You have actually created a second implementation in your header...

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one definition of each class member, but you have two

First one (implicit in class definition)

```
public:
AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType):Spaceship(float, float, float, float)
{}
```

and second at the source file

```
AlienSpaceship::AlienSpaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc, OrganismType race):Spaceship(health, food, cash, misc)
{
    this->race = race;
}
```

Choise one of this, either put

```
AlienSpaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc, OrganismType race):Spaceship(health, food, cash, misc)
{
    this->race = race;
}
```

into the class definition

either declare it at the class

```
class AlienSpaceship: public Spaceship{
OrganismType race;

public:
AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType);
```

and define at the source file

```
AlienSpaceship::AlienSpaceship(float health, float food, float cash, float misc, OrganismType race):Spaceship(health, food, cash, misc)
{
    this->race = race;
}
```

Also, declaration like this

```
AlienSpaceship(float, float, float, float, OrganismType):Spaceship(float, float, float, float)

is incorrect too. Actually, it conatains a part of defenition.
```